# MQTT / Mosquitto bridge not authorised with broker ACL

Tags: mqtt, acl, mosquitto

I have bridge to a Mosquitto broker that works fine. But it shows error: `Connection Refused: not authorised` when I try to use this simple ACL file on bridged broker:

```
user topic1_user
topic topic1/#
```

In my bridge config I have these settings under `Bridges` section:

```
connection bridge-conn1
address remotebroker:8887
topic topic1/# both
remote_username topic1_user
remote_password secret
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Show the config file for the remote broker, including the password file as well as the acl file

Answer (score 0):

So I was struggling with this very issue for a while.

My use-case:

I have a VerneMQ broker as cloud broker, then for each edge-client with x-amount of MQTT based applications running on each edge-device.

These Applications are connected to the local Mosquitto Bridge Broker on the edge-devices, So the communication is authenticated via the Bridge and each app just connects to the Bridge and all traffic if forwarded to the Cloud Broker with the edge-device-id as a prefix.

Now I was also getting this hideous `Connection Refused: not authorised` message and could not understand why, since if I tested user credentials on MQTTExplorer of MQTTX it work as expected.

But when browsing the logs of my VerneMQ broker I could see that the Bridges where trying to access the $SYS topic to tell the Cloud Broker of their connections.

There for the solution is to enable each client to write to this topic with their ClientID:

ACL File for Cloud Broker:

```
user admin
topic #

pattern device/%u/#
pattern $SYS/broker/connection/%c/#
```

`pattern device/%u/#` lets each bridge take the local traffic and publish it under `device/some_id/#`

`pattern $SYS/broker/connection/%c/#` lets each bridge notify and complete their connection and setup any topic forwarding

Now if the $SYS topic is structures the same for all brokers I don`t know, but this worked for me in my case useing VerneMQ and Mosquitto.

Mosquitto Logs Before enabling $SYS topic for Bridge:

```
1700743699: Bridge e36b28a2-d5bf-4a25-a048-7aea60b7b596 sending CONNECT
1700743699: Received CONNACK on connection local.e36b28a2-d5bf-4a25-a048-7aea60b7b596.
1700743699: Connection Refused: Not authorized
1700743699: Client local.e36b28a2-d5bf-4a25-a048-7aea60b7b596 closed its connection.
```

Mosquitto Logs After enabling $SYS topic for Bridge:

```
1700743841: Bridge e36b28a2-d5bf-4a25-a048-7aea60b7b596 sending CONNECT
1700743841: Received CONNACK on connection local.e36b28a2-d5bf-4a25-a048-7aea60b7b596.
1700743841: Bridge local.e36b28a2-d5bf-4a25-a048-7aea60b7b596 sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 2, Topic: device/e36b28a2-d5bf-4a25-a048-7aea60b7b596/#, QoS: 0, Options: 0x0c)
1700743841: Received SUBACK from local.e36b28a2-d5bf-4a25-a048-7aea60b7b596
```

From a fellow IoT dev, hope this helps anyone that is stuck!